# Weak convergence rates for integral operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-geometry

Suppose $q=\sum_{i=1}^m\pi_i\delta_{x_i}$ is a discrete measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $q\ast \varphi_\epsilon$ denote the convolution of $q$ with some mollifier $\varphi_\epsilon$, so that $q\ast\varphi_\epsilon \to q$ weakly as $\epsilon\to0$. Now define an integral operator by
$$
T\mu
:= \int K(x,y)\,d\mu(y).
$$

I want to say something like for "reasonable" choices of the kernel $K$, we have $$\text{TV}(Tq, T[q\ast\varphi_\epsilon]) = O(W(q, q\ast\varphi_\epsilon)), \quad(\ast)$$ where $\text{TV}$ is the usual total variation distance and $W$ is a Wasserstein distance of some order.

**My questions are:**

1. Are there simple counterexamples to show that this is in general false?
2. Are there conditions on $(K,\varphi_\epsilon)$ that guarantee something like $(\ast)$ holds?